# How can I make it so you input a "Worker code" and get the worker details same as when you "print(Worker_36.details)"? - Python

Tags: python

I am new to python and just playing around please help!

```
Worker_31 = Worker('David', 'Williamson',31 , 92500, 5, 37)
Worker_32 = Worker('Frank', 'Murphy',32 , 58500, 6, 27)
Worker_33 = Worker('Josephine', 'Dover',33 , 69500, 2, 30)
Worker_34 = Worker('Chester', 'Cohen',34 , 88500, 3, 52)
Worker_35 = Worker('Saba', "Brenland",35 , 96500, 4, 35)
Worker_36 = Worker('Tommy-Lee', 'Briggs',36 , 98500, 3, 57)
Worker_37 = Worker('Li', 'Hu-Tao',37 , 55000, 3, 22)
Worker_38 = Worker('Qin', 'Shi-Huang',38 ,14 ,1500000 , 34)
Worker_39 = Worker('Maximillian', 'Mendoza',39 , 200000, 13, 33)
Worker_40 = Worker('Sarah', 'Patel',40 , 86500 , 8, 29)
Worker_41 = Worker('Sumaiya', 'Johns',41 ,77900 , 10, 32)
```

So you see I was able to make the workers

```
def details(self):
    return '{}' '{}' '{}' '{}' '{}' '{}' '{}' '{}' '{}' '{}' '{}' '{}' '{}' '{}' '{}' .format("Your worker ", self.fullname(), " (Worker number ", self.number, ") ", "is paid a yearly salary of ", "$"+str(self.pay), " Dollars. ", "This worker has been with your company for ", self.time_with, " years, unfortunately however, they are due to retire in ", self.time_left, " years (aged 65).", " In the mean time however you can contact this worker with the email address ", self.email)
```

And able to print(Worker_36.details) for example and it works...

```
print("You have 50 workers what worker would you like to check the details of?")
Worker_Number_Check = input("Please input there worker number ")
```

If the user inputs 36 for example I want it to return the equavilent of the "print(Worker_36.details)"

I don't want to have to do a long else if for every single possible input number with a worker who has that as there "Worker number", please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of declaring many separate Worker variables, make a list of them:

```
workers = [
    Worker(...),
    Worker(...),
    Worker(...),
    Worker(...),
]
```

And then you can refer to `workers[36]`.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I think it would be good to make them as a list, but I don't get this part "And then you can refer to workers[36]"

Comment: `workers` is a list.  You refer to a specific item in a list via its index.  So `workers[0]` is the first item in the list, `workers[1]` is the second item, etc.

Comment: class Worker:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, number, pay, time_with, age):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.number = number
        self.pay = pay
        self.time_with = time_with
        self.age = age
        self.email = first_name + '.' + last_name + '@office-workers.com'
        self.time_left = int(65-age)

Comment: @TheStupidPerson Why did you post the class definition?  What are you asking?

Comment: Worker[
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Comment: does the list thing work in a class?

Comment: The list name is `workers`, exactly as I said in my answer.  `workers` is a list, containing many `Worker` object instances.

Comment: If you don't understand what a list is, perhaps you should work through some Python tutorials.

Comment: But yeah, I'm still working through Python tutorials on youtube...